# HttpClient receives 401 Response using NTLM authentication

Tags: c#, .net, ntlm

I have a C# Windows application running on .NET 4.6.1.  It is posting a SOAP message to a server using NTLM authentication.  It is expecting a 200 response, but receives the 401 response instead.  Here is the code:

```
HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler
{
    Credentials = CredentialManager.GetCredentials();
};

HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);

using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(uri, soapMessage, CancelToken))
{
    string soapResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        Parse(soapResponse);
    }
}
```

I know that there is always a 401 response sent in order to retrieve the credentials, but I thought that the HttpResponse was supposed to contain the final response, in this case a 200 message.  However, the response.StatusCode is always the 401 Unauthorized message, even though the developer on the server side assures me that immediately after the 401 message, a 200 message is sent.  How can I get the 200 response and ignore the 401 response?